# How can I show that $\sum_{k=0}^n [\frac{(n-2k)}{n}{n \choose k}]^2 = \frac{2}{n}{2n - 2 \choose n - 1}$?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I want to show this

$\sum_{k=0}^n [\frac{(n-2k)}{n}{n \choose k}]^2 = \frac{2}{n}{2n - 2 \choose n - 1}$

I tried to solve it using this identities:

I) $\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}^2 = {2n \choose n}$

II) ${n \choose k} = {n-1 \choose k-1}\frac{n}{k}$

III) ${n \choose k} = {n-1 \choose k-1} + {n-1 \choose k}$

Any hints?

Edit: I could solve it with a hint from TMM and the fact that $\sum_{k=0}^n {s \choose k}{r \choose n-k} = {s+r \choose n}$

Comment: I would pull out the 1/n^2 and move it to the RHS, then expand the square of (n-2k), split it into three sums, and solve each sum separately using your identities.

Comment: Success! what i also was missing was to use the identity:
$\sum_{k=0}^n {s \choose k}{r \choose n-k} = {s+r \choose n}$

Comment: @EnzoGiannotta: You could present your solution as answer to your question, if you like.

Comment: that is a good idea, i will do it when i have time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Solution**

$\sum_{k=0}^{n}[\frac{n-2k}{n}\binom{n}{k}]^{2}$

$= \frac{1}{n^{2}}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(n-2k)^2\binom{n}{k}^2 $

$=\frac{1}{n^{2}}[\sum_{k=0}^{n}n^2\binom{n}{k}^2 + 4\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^2\binom{n}{k}^2 - 4\sum_{k=0}^{n}nk\binom{n}{k}^2] $

$= \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^2 + \frac{4}{n^{2}}\sum_{k=0}^{n}n^2\binom{n-1}{k-1}^2 - \frac{4}{n^{2}}\sum_{k=0}^{n}n^2\binom{n-1}{k-1}\binom{n}{k}$ , here we use the fact that ${n \choose k} = {n-1 \choose k-1}\frac{n}{k}$ so $k{n \choose k} = n{n-1 \choose k-1}$

$= \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^2 + 4\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n-1}{k-1}^2 - 4\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n-1}{n-k}\binom{n}{k}$ , we use in the last sum: $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$ so $\binom{n-1}{k-1}=\binom{n-1}{n-k}$

Finally, knowing that:

$\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}^2 = {2n \choose n}$ and $\sum_{k=0}^n {s \choose k}{r \choose n-k} = {s+r \choose n}$

$= \binom{2n}{n} + 4\binom{2n-2}{n-1} - 4\binom{2n-1}{n} = \binom{2n}{n} + 4(\binom{2n-2}{n-1} - \binom{2n-1}{n})$

$= \binom{2n}{n} - 4\binom{2n-2}{n}$ , because ${n \choose k} = {n-1 \choose k-1} + {n-1 \choose k}$ then $ -{n-1 \choose k-1}={n-1 \choose k}-{n \choose k}$ in this case $\binom{2n-2}{n-1} - \binom{2n-1}{n} = -\binom{2n-2}{n}$

$= \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}-2^2\frac{(2n-2)!}{n!(n-2)!}$

$= \frac{(2n)!-2^2(2n-2)!n(n-1)}{(n!)^2}$

$= \frac{(2n)!-(2n-2)!(2n)2(n-1)}{(n!)^2} = \frac{(2n)!-(2n-2)!(2n)(2n-1 - 1)}{(n!)^2}$

$= \frac{(2n)!-(2n-2)!(2n)(2n-1) -(2n-2)!(2n)(-1) }{(n!)^2}$

$= \frac{(2n)!-(2n)! +(2n-2)!(2n) }{(n!)^2}$

$= \frac{(2n-2)!}{((n-1)!)^2}\frac{2}{n}$

$= \frac{2}{n}\binom{2n-2}{n-1}$